# How to allocate the elements of a matrix in c++ opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have always used the C API and am trying to convert a simple project to the C++ API to get a handle on it, but I can't seem to figure out how to allocate the elements of a matrix in C++.  For example, I have the following array:

```
double rotation[] = { 0, 1, 0,
                     -1, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 1 };
```

I have a 3x3 Mat, allocated with `Mat *rotation_vector = new Mat(3,3, CV_64FC1);`

In C, it would simply be `cvInitMatHeader(rotation_vector, 3, 3, CV_64FC1, rotation);`.  How is this done in C++?

Comment: If the C code works as you say (I know zip about opencv), then the C++ code will work in exactly the same way. Why do you think you have to use new?

Comment: Actually no.  The cvInitMatHeader only works with the old cvMat structures.  They don't work with the newer Mat objects

Comment: Well, don't use the new stuff then - or does it give you some new features? My point is that your old C code should compile under C++, possibly with a cast here and there.

Comment: because it is worth getting a handle on it?

Comment: The new c++ API is worth learning if only for the massive readability factor it adds to your code.  If you are using OpenCV in a c++ project, there's no good reason not to use its c++ features.

Answer (score 7):

You should use some variant of the cv::Mat object.

For small matrices where the size is known and *fixed*, you can use the cv::Matx object:

```
cv::Matx33d rotation(  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                      -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                       0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

For dynamically sized, arrays, you use the cv::Mat object

```
cv::Mat aBigMatrix( 53, 71, cv::CV_64FC1, cv::Scalar::all( 0.0 ) );
```

This would create a 2d-matrix with width of 53, height of 71, each element is a 64 bit floating point single-channel value ( basically a double ), and all of the elements will be set to 0.

Alternatively, you may use the cv::Mat_ template class, and the benefit is a cleaner initialization ( among other things ):

```
cv::Mat_<double> anotherBigMatrix( 53, 71, 0.0 );
```

This would create an equivalent matrix to the one described above.

Finally, you can use the template matrix class with an initialization list similar to the way you would do it in regular C:

There are many trade-offs to using the different classes, so you should make sure that you read the [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core__the_core_functionality.html) so that you pick the right one

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a header for your already-allocated data, do:

```
cv::Mat rotation_matrix(3, 3, CV_64FC1, rotation)
```

this will make Mat a header for this data (no data will be copied). If you want to copy it to a new matrix, you can do:

```
cv::Mat new_matrix = rotation_matrix.clone();
```

You do not want to use `new` with `cv::Mat` (in almost all cases), it is a reference-counted datatype - think of it as a smart pointer. What was `CvMat*` should be `cv::Mat` (note the lack of a `*`).